# "Current user did not login to the application!" error when function call from service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, boilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

In a service I have wrote a simple function to get tenant id of particular user

```
    [AbpAuthorize]
    public int? FindTenancyNameByUserNameOrEmail(string userNameOrEmail)
    {
        var qry = (from p in _memberRepository.GetAll()
                   where p.UserName == userNameOrEmail || p.EmailAddress == userNameOrEmail
                   select p).FirstOrDefault();
        if (qry != null)
        {
            return qry.TenantId;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("User not found");
        }
    }
```

I am calling this function from login function of account controller.

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel, string returnUrl = "", string returnUrlHash = "")
    {
        var tenancyid = _memberAppService.FindTenancyNameByUserNameOrEmail(loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress.Trim());
        //bla bla code
    }
```

I get following error:

> Exception thrown: 'Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException' in
>   Abp.dll
>
> Additional information: Current user did not login to the application!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the user was not belonging to the tenant.

Used the following line to set the tenant id and code worked.

```
CurrentUnitOfWork.SetFilterParameter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant, AbpDataFilters.Parameters.TenantId, intTenancyId);
```

added the `[AbpAllowAnonymous]` attribute to the service method

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in first line

```
 var qry = (from p in _memberRepository.GetAll()
```

.GetAll() function create this error as you cannot use Builtin function in linq query.

Instead use

```
var Myvariable = _memberRepository.GetAll().ToList();
var qry = (from p in Myvariable where p.UserName == userNameOrEmail || p.EmailAddress == userNameOrEmail select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is AbpAuthorize Attribute **[AbpAuthorize]** remove it.